# How would I rebuild this JSON Object with JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, object

```
{
"oozie": {
    "admin": {},
    "hosts-list": [
        "1"
    ],
    "hostsinfo": [
        {
            "host-id": "1",
            "details": "Failed ProcessHealthMonitor health check 1 times consecutively",
            "currstatus": "Warning",
            "currstatusclass": "warning"
        },
        {
            "host-id": "2",
            "details": "Failed ProcessHealthMonitor health check 1 times consecutively",
            "currstatus": "Warning",
            "currstatusclass": "warning"
        },
        {
            "host-id": "4",
            "details": "Failed ProcessHealthMonitor health check 1 times consecutively",
            "currstatus": "Warning",
            "currstatusclass": "warning"
        },
        {
            "host-id": "5",
            "details": "Failed ProcessHealthMonitor health check 1 times consecutively",
            "currstatus": "Warning",
            "currstatusclass": "warning"
        }
    ],
    "status": [
        {}
    ]
},
"single-namenode": {
    "admin": {},
    "hosts-list": [
        "1"
    ],
    "hostsinfo": [
        {
            "host-id": "1",
            "details": "Running Service",
            "currstatus": "Running",
            "currstatusclass": "success"
        }
    ],
    "status": [
        {}
    ]
},
"single-database": {
    "admin": {},
    "hosts-list": [
        "1"
    ],
    "hostsinfo": [
        {
            "host-id": "1",
            "details": "Running Service",
            "currstatus": "Running",
            "currstatusclass": "success"
        }
    ],
    "status": [
        {}
    ]
},
"secondarynamenode": {
    "admin": {},
    "hosts-list": [
        "1"
    ],
    "hostsinfo": [
        {
            "host-id": "1",
            "details": "Running Service",
            "currstatus": "Running",
            "currstatusclass": "success"
        }
    ],
    "status": [
        {}
    ]
},
"datanode": {
    "admin": {},
    "hosts-list": [
        "1"
    ],
    "hostsinfo": [
        {
            "host-id": "1",
            "details": "Failed HttpHealthMonitor health check 2 times consecutively",
            "currstatus": "Warning",
            "currstatusclass": "warning"
        }
    ],
    "status": [
        {}
    ]
},
"web": {
    "admin": {},
    "hosts-list": [
        "1"
    ],
    "hostsinfo": [
        {
            "host-id": "1",
            "details": "Setting Master IP",
            "currstatus": "Dead",
            "currstatusclass": "error"
        }
    ],
    "status": [
        {}
    ]
},
"tasktracker": {
    "admin": {},
    "hosts-list": [
        "1"
    ],
    "hostsinfo": [
        {
            "host-id": "1",
            "details": "Running Service",
            "currstatus": "Running",
            "currstatusclass": "success"
        }
    ],
    "status": [
        {}
    ]
},
"jobtracker": {
    "admin": {},
    "hosts-list": [
        "1"
    ],
    "hostsinfo": [
        {
            "host-id": "1",
            "details": "Running Master Service",
            "currstatus": "Running",
            "currstatusclass": "success"
        }
    ],
    "status": [
        {}
    ]
}
}
```

Ive been at it for days trying to figure this one out and I just can't nail it. I have no control over the actual JSON object and how its output looks like. However I have an entirely different need for it that in its current structure has posed nothing but issues for me.

What I want to do preferably with jQuery is

get the names of the Main objects
Oozie, Single-namenode, single-database, secondarynamenode, etc...
and rebuild an object for storage that follows a more practical format for use.

What I would like to see in the end is a new object that looks similar to

```
{ 
  "myservices":{[
     {"name":"oozie", "host-id": "1", "details":"failed process health monitor....", "currstatus":"Warning", "currstatusclass":"warning"},
     {"name":"oozie", "host-id": "2", "details":"failed process health monitor....", "currstatus":"Warning", "currstatusclass":"warning"},
     {"name":"oozie", "host-id": "3", "details":"failed process health monitor....", "currstatus":"Warning", "currstatusclass":"warning"},
     {"name":"oozie", "host-id": "4", "details":"failed process health monitor....", "currstatus":"Warning", "currstatusclass":"warning"},
     {"name":"oozie", "host-id": "5", "details":"failed process health monitor....", "currstatus":"Warning", "currstatusclass":"warning"},
     {"name":"single-namenode", "host-id": "2", "details":"failed process health monitor....", "currstatus":"Warning", "currstatusclass":"warning"}

  ]}
```

My Latest failed attempt is:

```
$('.refreshAllb').click(function() {
    var outputCon = '';
    $.getJSON('services.json', function(data) {
        $('#master_service_container').empty();
        $.each(data, function(i, object){
            $.each(object, function(property, value){
                if(property == "hostsinfo")
                {
                    $.each(value, function(propertyX, valueX){
                        outputCon += propertyX[valueX] +'<br>';
                    });
                }
            });
        });
        $('#master_service_container').html(outputCon);
    });
});
```

As I said Im Ive been at this for days I am at my wits end, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example. Note that your required output is invalid JSON. The `myservices` property cannot be an object and array as in your example. It should be either an object (associative array) or a standard javascript array:

```
var input = ... the original object

var output = { myservices: [] };
for (var key in input) {
    if (input.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        for (var i = 0, hostsinfo = input[key].hostsinfo; i < hostsinfo.length; i++) {
            output.myservices.push({
                'name': key,
                'host-id': hostsinfo[i]['host-id'],
                'details': hostsinfo[i]['details'],
                'currstatus': hostsinfo[i]['currstatus'],
                'currstatusclass': hostsinfo[i]['currstatusclass']
            });
        }
    }
}

// TODO: use the output
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/erean/3/).

Comment: I think you were missing this from version 1 `var hostsinfo = input[key].hostsinfo[i]`

Comment: @NickyWaites, no, there is already a `var` inside the `for` loop. In javascript you can have a single var statement and declare multiple variables separated by commas.

Comment: I am returning undefined for all but the "name" of each even in the live demo in the console.log() it shows them as undefined. Its a hell of a lot better then where I was 20 minutes ago though

Comment: adding [i] to the hostinfo[...] inside the push fixed'r up.

Comment: @chris, you are correct, it should be `hostsinfo[i][...]` inside the loop. I have updated my post and the jsfiddle accordingly. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @Darin To be fair I was referring to your jsFiddle version 1 but I see you've updated it to something similar.  http://jsfiddle.net/erean/4/

Comment: @DarinDimitrov the output is it equivilant an array or an object I know both are close in formations but entirely different to work with. Like right now I am trying to figure it out so I can sort through the results and list them per name or per host-id I dunno what it is usually JSON and me get along fine, but this one is just a thorn in my side. I appreciate the help thus far though thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
function restructure(data) {
  var result = {myservices: []}, i, name;

  for (name in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(name) && data[name].hostsinfo !== undefined) {
      for (i = 0; i < data[name].hostsinfo.length; i += 1) {
        result.myservices.push($.extend({name: name}, data[name].hostsinfo[i]));
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
}

// with data being your input data
console.log(data, restructure(data));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = {};
var myservices = [];
$.each(data.oozie.hostsinfo,function(key,value){
    var temp = {}
    temp.name = "oozie";
    temp.host-id = value.host-id;
    temp.details = value.details;
    temp.currstatus = value.currstatus;
    temp.currstatusclass = value.currstatusclass;
    myservices.push(temp);
})
$.each(data.single-namenode.hostsinfo,function(key,value){
    var temp = {}
    temp.name = "single-namenode";
    temp.host-id = value.host-id;
    temp.details = value.details;
    temp.currstatus = value.currstatus;
    temp.currstatusclass = value.currstatusclass;
    myservices.push(temp);
})
result.myservices = myservices;
```

Comment: very tempted to try that. only thing is that many each is a bit obtrusive in the long run. Trust if it works though it may be a last resort for me. But again its only cause I want to try avoid running 8+ each statements consecutively